# Discord bot Hikari join voice

Tags: python, discord

I can't find any videos about it, found what is the code but no idea of how to use it.

```
async def connect_to(
    guild: snowflakes.SnowflakeishOr[guilds.Guild],
    channel: snowflakes.SnowflakeishOr[channels.GuildVoiceChannel],
    voice_connection_type: Type[_VoiceConnectionT],
    *,
    deaf: bool = False,
    mute: bool = False,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> _VoiceConnectionT: ...
```

I want to know from where snowflake is defined.

Comment: https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/snowflakes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A snowflake represents a unique ID on discord.

This is documented [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes).

This function you are looking at is an internal hikari function.
The one you actually want to use is `hikari.GatewayBot.update_voice_state`.

This is documented [here](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/bot.html#hikari.impl.bot.GatewayBot.update_voice_state).

Ex:

```py
await bot.update_voice_state(1234, 5678)
```

Where 1234 is the guild id, and 5678 is the voice channel id.

Inversely you can disconnect from voice like so:

```py
await bot.update_voice_state(1234, None)
```

Passing `None` to the channel ID disconnects.